# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a website, and I **rarely** get the error in the title. I know one possible solution for the error is by changing max_connections, but other than that I get this error as well:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /db_managers/read_plans.php on line 20
```

I'm not sure which one causes the other one. Regarding the Too many connections error I've contacted my hosting company to see whet the number max_connections is. In regards to the other error, this is my implementation:

1. index.php:

   ```
   <?php 
   require_once("layout/plans.php");

   print_price_list($page);
   ?>
   ```
2. plans.php:

   ```
   <?php
   require_once("db_managers/read_plans.php");

   $results = read_plans();
   // by a foreach loop I display elements of $results array
   ?>
   ```
3. read_plans.php:

   ```
   <?php
   require_once("singleton.php");

   function read_plans() {
   $db = Database::getConnection();
   $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM the_table ORDER BY id DESC ");
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

   return $result;
   ?>
   ```
4. singleton.php:

   ```
   <?php
   require_once("database.php");

   class Database {

   private static $db;

   private function __construct(){
   self::$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOSTNAME.";dbname=".DATABASE.";charset=utf8", USERNAME, PASSWORD);
   self::$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
   }

   public static function getConnection() {
   if(!isset(self::$db))
      new Database();

   return self::$db;
   }

   ?>
   ```

Is there any issue in this implementation that causes the error in read_plans.php? Or maybe it's because of that the website is on a shared hosting?

Comment: once you have created the object of Database and called getConnection, that will constantly be in memory even after the read_plans function has finished executing. With a PDO you need to unset the PDO object to get the PDO to close the connection. Or it will constantly hold the connection open. If you have a LOT of simultaneous traffic then you could exceed the max connections. Also if you are on a shared host there could be a limit on the database server itself. I would consider making a static destroyConnection() function if you are constantly having problems.

Comment: Do not follow the above comment, it will make things worse.

Comment: what is the the_table size?

Comment: @DarylB Thanks. But I thought the connection is destroyed automatically after each query execution

Comment: you are confusing SQL query execution with HTTP request.

Comment: Have you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @Bek It was cheap hosting company, when I migrated to a better hosting company with a better quality the problem resolved.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure which one causes the other one.

One which goes first.

> I've contacted my hosting company

You don't need no hosting company to see the number, `SELECT @@max_connections;` will do.

> Is there any issue in this implementation

It's quite unusual but at glance it doesn't create multiple connections. So, most likely the issue is caused by slow queries. Do you have any?

Comment: I wish you were my common sense! Anyway.

Comment: I used try and catch, and set an email which the error is sent to it. So, I got too many connections in email, and another error was displayed on browser. So I'm not sure which one is the first one. Regarding the number of connections it's 150, thanks for that. table has got only 4 rows and  14 columns for each. Is it unusual? I followed discussions in stackoverflow to implement it. How can I identify slow queries? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With only 14 rows it should be blazing fast. May be it's indeed your sharing hosting neighbors who ate up all the connections. You should always log your errors instead of catching them and check logs regularily.

Comment: It's a reseller account, there are only 3 domains on this server. Just a quick question. So in order to destroy the db connection do I need to have $db = null; after each query?

Comment: 1. you should NEVER destroy a connection after each query. 2. To destroy a connection after ALL queries got executed is *possible* but there is very little point in it anyway.

Comment: Well, I checked error_log. It's got many similar warnings such as: "PHP Startup: PDO: Unable to initialize module", "pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module", ... I contacted hosting company to update the PHP modules as well. Maybe it resolves the issue